# What is " / " used for in Ms Access query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have the following query

```
SELECT EtichetteLingue.IdAltreLingue, EtichetteLingue.EtiLinDesc, 
       [Etichette].[DocNr] & 
       IIf([Etichette_1].[lingua] Is Not Null, 
           " / " & [Etichette_1].[DocNr]) AS ALDocNr
FROM (EtichetteLingue 
LEFT JOIN Etichette ON EtichetteLingue.EtiLinLingua1 = Etichette.idEti) 
LEFT JOIN Etichette AS Etichette_1 ON EtichetteLingue.EtiLinLingua2 = Etichette_1.idEti;
```

Can you please tell me what " / " is used for ? and what is it's sql server 2005 query equivalent?

Comment: "/" & value > is just a string joining function.

Comment: it's not used for anything. that is just string concatenation where it's adding a backslash between the values from the 2 columns. if you run the sql, you see backslahes in the `ALDocNr` column right?

Comment: also, i think there's an error in the `IIF`, as the null checked column is not referenced inside the statement, so it should probably read: `IIf([Etichette_1].[lingua] Is Not Null, " / " & [Etichette_1].[lingua]) AS ALDocNr`

Comment: The sql server equivalent would be to replace the double-quotes with single-quotes:    ' / '

Comment: And for SQL versions prior to 2012 the IIF function will need to be replaced with a CASE statement.